# Can I use BreadcrumbList Structured Data on my site if I don't display a breadcrumb trail on the page or in my URL structure?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

I have read that breadcrumbs help Google understand the structure of your site better so I would like to implement it on mine. However, I don't currently have a breadcrumb trail that's visible on the site. Is this against best practices to have the markup, but not display it visually for the user?

Also, I do not have breadcrumbs in my URL structure. So on article pages the URL is like so: `https://example.com/article-slug/`, and sub-category pages do not show the upper-level category: e.g., I use `https://example.com/camping-gear/` instead of `https://example.com/outdoors/camping-gear`.

Can I still implement `BreadcrumbList` despite these two factors?

---

As per the comment on an answer below: I should clarify that, while I don't have a visible breadcrumb trail, I *do* have a navigational menu that the SD markup would follow. In other words - the links will not misrepresent or mislead users, as the same *links* in the breadcrumb markup will be present on every page of the site.

Comment: What would you put in your breadcrumbs if you don't actually have any?  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Well there is still a hierarchy on my site. I just chose not to indicate it in the URL structure and I'm not currently showing a trail on the site. The main point of my wanting to add BreadcrumbList is to better help Google understand the architecture of my site.

Comment: If I put a visible breadcrumb trail with links on the site, is it ok to use the markup then, given that my URL structure does not have a trail?

Comment: Your [comment below](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123382/can-i-use-breadcrumblist-structured-data-on-my-site-if-i-dont-display-a-breadcr/123398#comment166636_123398) offers useful distinction: Are navigation menus considered breadcrumbs? For example, would a menu of sub-page links warrant structured breadcrumb data? It might help to include an example of your navigational menu in your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this against best practices to have the markup, but not display it
>   visually for the user?

This contradicts **[the following points of Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#content)**:

> Don't mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page. For
>   example, if the JSON-LD markup describes a performer, the HTML body
>   should describe that same performer.

In his guide **[Manual Actions report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175)** Google considers structured data link to hidden content as a spam signal:

> Structured data found on hidden content    Structured data found on
>   elements that are not visible to the user.

Comment: I should clarify that while I don't have a visible breadcrumb trail, I _do_ have a navigational menu that the SD markup would follow. In other words - the links will not misrepresent or mislead users, as the _same links_ in the breadcrumb markup will be present on every page of the site.

Comment: @ABiron That's a good question: Are navigation menus considered breadcrumbs? For example, would a menu of sub-page links warrant structured breadcrumb data? Does it depend on the structure of the menu?